# Disable Horizontal scrolling javascript

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, scroll

Is there anyway to disable horizontal scrolling in javascript? I am using the following:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

However, this disables scrolling altogether. I have also set the `overflow-x` to hidden.

```
.layer{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I need to do this for a mobile application on android.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note: Answer copy-pasted [from this source](http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript/34617-how-disable-horizontal-scrolling.html#post152090).

You can use following code with reference to particular frames to hide both scrollbars:

```
style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden"
style="overflow:-moz-scrollbars-horizontal;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;"
```

x- is used for horizontal,y- for vertical

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please note that [copy-pasting answers is discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295778/is-copy-pasting-content-from-other-websites-without-citation-acceptable) without citations. I have added a citation just for the record. Thank you, and welcome to StackOverflow (although this isn't perhaps the friendliest of welcomes...).

Comment: Thanks for this, After suffering with this for 16 hours, I eventually restructured my html pages. I fixed all the layers that won't be changing in the app and disabled scrolling with overflow hidden. Only the content layer which needs scrolling has the overflow-y: scroll set because i only need vertical scrolling. So everything seems okay now.

Comment: Just as a note if ever anyone starts up a mobile app project it is best to stick to the standard page structure to avoid these kind of issues. Keep uniformity throughout the app(eg follow the jquery mobile page structure as it is stated to be used)....lesson learnt the hard way